# How to filter and show only the polygon that contains the points of the properties

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm inserting an executable code below that shows the points of certain properties by inserting into a map. I inserted brief explanations in the code so that you understand what I did. What I would like is: see that it is showing the whole map, but I would like to filter and show only the polygon that contains the points of the properties, how can I do that?

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import warnings
from shapely.errors import ShapelyDeprecationWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ShapelyDeprecationWarning) 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create map
url = "https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip"

map = gpd.read_file(url)
   
#Property coordinates
Points_properties = pd.DataFrame({'Properties':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'Latitude':[-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267],
    'Longitude':[-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702]})

# Create a geometry column for Points_properties

Points_properties['geometry']= None

for index, row in Points_properties.iterrows():
    Points_properties.loc[index,'geometry'] = Point(row.Longitude, row.Latitude)

Points=gpd.GeoDataFrame(Points_properties,geometry='geometry')

# Showing property points on the map
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
Points.plot(ax=ax)
map.plot(ax=ax,facecolor="None",edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

**Error**

```
C:\Users\Jovani Souza\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7508\2533860563.py:33: UserWarning: CRS mismatch between the CRS of left geometries and the CRS of right geometries.
Use `to_crs()` to reproject one of the input geometries to match the CRS of the other.

Left CRS: None
Right CRS: GEOGCS["GCS_SIRGAS_2000",DATUM["D_SIRGAS_2000",SPH ...

  joined = gpd.sjoin(points_properties, municipios, how='left', predicate ='intersects')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use [`geopandas.points_from_xy`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) to convert the latitude and longitude columns into a GeometryArray:

```py
points_properties = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'Properties':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'geometry': gpd.points_from_xy(
        [-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267],
        [-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702],
    ),
})
```

Now, you can get the join of the points and the geometries with [`geopandas.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html):

```py
url = (
    "https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/"
    "malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/"
    "UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip"
)

municipios = gpd.read_file(url)

joined = gpd.sjoin(points_properties, municipios, how='left', predicate ='intersects')
```

The result will have the index and polygon of the points_properties dataframe, but will contain additional rows from the polygon. So you could plot only the regions containing any points with something like the following:

```py
municipios[municipios.CD_GEOCMU.isin(joined.CD_GEOCMU)].plot()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Michael, but in `joined` it gave error. Please, can you test your code again?

Comment: I saw that you adjusted your code, and I tried, however, it gave error again, but I believe it is another error now. I'll insert it in the question the error so you can see.

Comment: this works for me on the latest version of geopandas. sorry my previous post had syntax from a couple versions ago, but this should be fine. a warning is not the same as an error - geopandas is just warning you here that the coordinate system of the points doesn't match that of the shapefile. Your example doesn't have a CRS so this must be something particular to your points data. You can use [`points_properties.to_crs(municipios .crs)`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) before sjoin to align them :)