# convert polygon recorded as object to shapely polygon gives 'str' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely

Initially, I have 2 datasets. One is dataset with 45 polygons defined in Excel and another one is geometric coordinates of points. I need to know for each geometric point in which of 45 polygons it locates.

For file with polygons, I have a csv file which recorded POLYGON(......) as objects. I want to later check whether polygon contains point with shapely. I thought that it already was polygon type, but when I import it from csv, it imports just as a string. I tried to convert this data to Polygon()

Each raw in df looks smth like (shortened on purpose)

```
POLYGON ((37.667289733886719 55.700740814208984,37.670955657958984 55.70050048828125)
```

As suggest, I also printed the first 5 raws of this dataset:

```
print(io.head(5))

                                                 WKT  IO_ID  Unnamed: 2
0  POLYGON ((37.667289733886719 55.70074081420898...     28         NaN
1  POLYGON ((37.671272277832031 55.62009048461914...     29         NaN
2  POLYGON ((37.713523864746094 55.77525711059570...     24         NaN
3  POLYGON ((37.700267791748047 55.72071075439453...     25         NaN
4  POLYGON ((37.783447265625 55.648544311523438,3...     26         NaN
```

And if I check datatypes of columns with polygon - it is an object format

```
df.dtype

WKT            object
IO_ID           int64
Unnamed: 2    float64
dtype: object
```

```
for polygon in df.WKT:
  polygon = Polygon(polygon)
```

And it give me the error:  'str' object has no attribute '**array_interface**'

I can't get why this happens and what can be done (I confess I am completely new to geodata). My understanding that instead of object format I need to have the data in polygon format, but somehow i can't change it to it.

Comment: it sounds like the df already contains data of type polygon. But I think it would be helpful to step back and know more about what you're trying to do. If you're trying to map a dataframe of points to a dataframe of polygons, check out [`geopandas.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html)

Comment: could you try to describe more about what you're trying to do, what the code you have so far is doing, what the data types you're working with are (e.g. - it sounds like df might actually be a pandas.Series?) and paste the result of `print(df)` for the various objects you're working with as a code block. Ideally, it would be helpful if you could create a [mre]. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks a lot! I tried to update as you suggested and now it gave me slighly another issue, but still does not work.

Comment: maybe you should write own function to parse string with `POLYGON(...)` - simply remove string `POLYGON(` and `)` and split on `,` and `space` and use `float()` to covert values.

Comment: few days/weeks ago was other question about some polygons in shapely. Original object had box/rectangle as pair with `top left` corner and `bottom right` corner - `(x1, y1, x2, y2)` - but `shapely` needed as 4 corners `[ (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y2), (x2, y1) ]`

Comment: someone else is having a very similar issue to you! this post might be helpful, though there's a lot going on and so it's a bit hard to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72364975/3888719

Comment: error may suggest that `polygon` is normal string but it expects something different - some array with many values. You can confirm this with `python( type(polygon) )`

Comment: @furas - FYI in case you come across something like this again - [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) is a pretty common geospatial encoding used for serialization, in a number of storage formats, and by some spatial databases. it's a pretty straightforward spec but it's not worth parsing by yourself - lots of languages/frameworks have WKT parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the spatial features of geopandas, your shapes need to be geometry type, not strings. You can see what type the objects are using the `dtype` attribute - you should see something like the following:

```py
In [6]: df.geometry.dtype
Out[6]: <geopandas.array.GeometryDtype at 0x17a0934c0>
```

If instead the output says something like `dtype('O')`, then you just have strings and need to convert them to a GeometryArray.

It looks like your shapes are in the ["well known text" (aka wkt) format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry). You can convert a wkt column to a geometry column with [`geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt.html):

```py
# replace string geometry representations with shapely geometries
df['geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['WKT'])

# initialize GeoDataFrame with the result
# ('geometry' is the default geometry column name)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
```

At this point your GeoDataFrame gdf should have all the spatial features of geopandas, and could be used to join to a GeometryArray of points using [`geopandas.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html). Note that a regular DataFrame of points will need to first be converted into a GeoDataFrame using [`geopandas.points_from_xy`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) - see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72297421/3888719) for an example.